# Collocation for getting a dental filling

Tags: words, collocations

I wanted to tell a friend about a time when I had to get a dental filling. My instinct was to use 受ける or もらう, but Google tells me this is incorrect. Would I simply say:

> 去年、歯が詰め物した。

or perhaps

> 去年、歯が詰め物してしまった。

Furthermore, what actually happened was I had to have a filling replaced. Is this correct?

> 詰め物した歯を交換してくれた。

(Edit: I just realized this means I'm replacing the tooth, not the filling. 歯の詰め物, not 詰め物がした歯, right?)

And is 歯 required? In English, "I got a filling" clearly implies "dental filling," but I get the sense that this is not the case in Japanese. Thanks!

Comment: Why use 「が」 at all?

Comment: Would it be 歯を詰め物した？I'm trying to understand the proper collocations. Thanks. Or の？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say:

> 歯に詰め物をした
>   歯を詰めた

You can use もらう as a subsidiary verb, as in:

> 歯に詰め物をしてもらった
>   歯に詰め物を入れてもらった
>   歯を詰めてもらった

<sub>To say "I had a tooth filled with [some material]", you can say 「歯に［樹脂・白いもの・レジン etc.］を詰めた・詰めてもらった」.</sub>

---

To say "I had a filling replaced", you could say:

> 歯の詰め物を交換した (or 交換してもらった)

... but I think it's more common to say:

> 歯を詰め直した
>   歯を詰め直してもらった

---

> And is 歯 required? In English, "I got a filling" clearly implies "dental filling," but I get the sense that this is not the case in Japanese.

Yes... you'd usually need to say 「歯」...  <sub>though I think you could leave it out when you just said 「歯医者（さん）で...」, like 「昨日、歯医者さんで詰め物をしてもらった。」... But 「昨日、歯医者さんで詰めた。」 still sounds a bit strange...</sub>

Answer (score 1):

In this case,  for filling a tooth with ceramic, silver, resins, etc. you can say

> 歯に詰め物をした。

or

you can say X as the fillings.

> Xで歯を詰めた。

Considering the collocations 歯 with が, when your teeth fell out,

> 歯が抜けた.

When your wisdom teeth touching back teeth,

> 親知らずが奥歯に当たる.